# Не открывается файл

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Уже теряюсь в догадках.
Не открывается файл, имя которого передано через сокет от клиента серверу.
Передается все правильно, если только добавляется какой-нибудь перевод строки.
Может надо переделать из  `char[]` в строку?

```
  char buffer[1024];

  ....(тут recv  через сокет), в буфере при отладке "С:/6.pro"
  FILE *in = fopen(buffer, "r");
  if(in == NULL) printf("Error opening file");
  else printf("File was successfully opened");
```

Comment: в задании так
2. Клиент посылает серверу запрос, содержащий путь искомого файла и размер блока  на который должен разбиваться файл.
3. Сервер ищет файл и поблочно пересылает файл, записываемый клиентом (в случае отсутствия искомого файла выдается сообщение об ошибке).

Comment: А ну пусть поблочно, для успокоения нервов преподавателя. Цикл fread -- send. Блоками (хотя само соединение -- труба, точнее две трубы -- туда и обратно, и никаких разделителей блоков там изначально нет).

Comment: @АннаХатико, один маленький совет по отладке. Обычно все наглядно при примерно такой печати строк, содержимое которых "сомнительно"

    printf ("buf: [%s]\n",buf);

пробелы и т.п. в начале или в конце буфера сразу бросаются в глаза. И еще проверяйте результаты вызова и при ошибке всегда печатайте их, вызывайте perror(), а не ограничивайтесь сообщением типа "не могу открыть файл".

Кстати, еще одно замечание. Не стоит в send() посылать весь буфер ( BUF_SIZE). Правильней ограничится только байтами, относящимися к делу.

--

(еще один совет не влезает. см продолжение)

Comment: (продолжение)

 И учтите, в recv() Вы можете получить только часть посланных за один send() сообщения. Да, TCP это поток байт, в нем нет никаких "отметок" от каждого из send(). Реально recv() вернет min из количества запрошенных и находящихся в буфере ОС данных. Для localhost или быстрой и незагруженной сети получение части посланных данных нехарактерно.

Поэтому на этот момент редко обращают внимание в демо-программах, но его **обязательно** надо иметь в виду. В реальных протоколах либо в начале порции данных передают ее длину, либо используют маркер конца. У Вас это м.б. '\\n' или '\\0'.

Comment: @avp Читать, пока результатом recv() не будет 0. Если приём блокирующий (по умолчанию), то значит больше ничего и не будет.

Comment: @alexlz, 0 из recv() это значит, что клиент сделал close() (или shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR), что в протоколах программ данного уровня редкость). 

Если close(), то все - ответ уже не передать. Поэтому в данном случае получение 0 из recv() это конец соединения (скорее всего клиент получил ^C).

Comment: @alexlz, nc может и закрывает (в зависимости от ситуации). Речь о программах студентов.

Вообще, я уже не понимаю, мы обсуждаем конкретную проблему автора или как **надо** программировать клиент-серверное приложение? 

Если последнее, то все равно надо с конкретикой (с ТЗ так сказать) определиться.

Comment: @avp Как я понимаю, в учебном задании @АннаХатико сервер должен передать файл и закрыть соединение. А более общие вопросы клиент-серверных решений -- темы других обсуждений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм. Примерно так

```
 fgets(buff, BUF_SIZE, stdin);
 n = strlen(buff);
 if (buff[n-1] == '\n') --n;
 send(my_socket, buff, n, 0);
```

Передавать не весь buff, а только нужные символы.

Comment: теперь возник такой вопрос: когда пересылается путь к файлу - для некоторых файлов приклеивается к имени кракозябры рандомные, поэтому они не открываются.. как этого избежать? это вообще происходит для файлов, которые нельзя просчитать..

Comment: buffer "D:\data2.txtДю^UХJw" 
вот такое например..(

Comment: вы строку завершайте нуль символом.

Comment: на сервер приходит в таком виде

Comment: на сервер приходит норм, но ты не завершаешь нуль символом и он тупо показывает тебе все значения в памяти после принятых данных пока не попадётся нульсимвол. 

попробуйте принимать данные и в конец принятых данных записывайте в ручную нуль символ.
к примеру:

    int size = recv(socket, buff, n ,0);
    buff[size] = '\0';

точно не скажу...

Comment: на клиенте длина буфера 12, на сервер приходит 24

Comment: кстати, если fgets предоставляет нуль символ, то посылайте на 1 больше.

    send(my_socket, buff, n + 1, 0);

Comment: может здесь что не так
if(recv(client_socket, &buffer[0], BUFFER_SIZE, 0) != SOCKET_ERROR)

Comment: А нельзя ли полностью поместить тексты в вопрос? Только новый вопрос открывать не надо.

Comment: сейчас вообще 28 на сервер пришло

Comment: Насколько я понимаю (по метке vc++) речь идет о винде. В ней fgets() считает в буфер строку, завершающуюся не одним '\\n', а **двумя символами '\\r''\\n'**. Это надо учитывать.

@АннаХотико, для отладки **печатайте** и в клиенте и в сервере **результат**, возвращаемый **всеми** send() и recv() **и содержимое буфера** (естественно только отправленные/принятые байты).

Comment: @alexlz, у меня там комментарии кончились. Здесь наверное тоже заканчиваются. В общем - дурь.

--

Что надо сделать в задании я понимаю. Проблема (как я ее вижу) в том, что не принимается имя файла. После ее решения сервер должен отправить файл (while((l=read(...)) > 0) send(...);) и просто закрыть соединение, а клиент правильно на это отреагировать.

Реально ее проблема видимо в том, что клиент отправляет вместе с именем файла лишние байты, а сервер не завершает нулем принято имя.


Прием на сервере recv()-ом не всех посланных одним send()-ом данных на данном этапе можно не учитывать.

Comment: @avp Откуда дровишки про `\r\n`? Ежели мне не изменяет склероз, то это забота рантайма (с терминологии gnu -- libc), который должен эту пару заменять на `\n`. А вот передавать клиенту лучше имя с `\n` или '\0` в конце, которые сервер должен отлавливать, принимая по одному байту (на случай хитрого маршрута, длинного и медленного, где единственный recv() может всё имя сразу и не принять.

Comment: @alexlz, согласен, про \\r\\n Вы правы. Сам обычно просто удаляю их своей функцией delcrnl() во всех протоколах, поэтому ошибся.

А читать по одному байту - это перебор. Да, при чтении сразу буфера  программа несколько усложняется, но об эффективности думать все равно надо.

Comment: @alexlz, дело не в спичках. Дело в том, что все надо делать правильно (или хотя бы задумываться об этом).

Вас никогда не поражало, насколько медленно работают современные девайсы, хотя их "сырая" производительность превосходит Cray-1?

Comment: @avp Надеюсь у @АннаХатико не такой въедливый преподаватель (а уж про изобретателя "design pattern"ов и вспоминать не будем).

А насчёт "современных девайсов" где-то у пионера веб-приложений П.Грэма было в его эссе.

Comment: `Premature optimization` же. Сначала - хороший код, потом оптимизация `hotspot'ов`.

Comment: @tomcat Nicht verstehen. Какими словарями нужно пользоваться для расшифровки Вашей фразы?

Answer (score 1):

- Протестируйте ваш код с `fopen("С:/6.pro", "r")`. Что получилось?
- Может быть, в вашем буфере оказывается не нуль-терминированная строка?
- Потенциально (хотя очень вряд ли) может не быть соответствующих `permission'ов` для файла.
- `fopen` такие вещи прожевывает, но все-таки у вас неправильный слэш в пути `"C:/6.pro".`
- Это оффтоп, но если вы ставите тэг `C++,` то используйте `std::ifstream` или `std::istreambuf_iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, закрываете ли вы этот файл до того, как открыли снова, посмотрите что в переменной `errno` после данного вызова:

```
char *str;
...

if(in == NULL) {
 str = strerrno(errno);
 printf("Error opening file - %s",str);
}
```